Next.js: How can I cache data that will only change once a day?
I have a single page application using Next.js. I am building a website similar to https://nflscorigami.com/ but for the NBA. In my postgresql database I have a table with about 70k rows that consists of every NBA game played.
In my trpc API I have
getGames: publicProcedure.query(async ({ ctx }) => {
    const allGames = await ctx.db.query.nbaGames.findMany();

    return {
      games: allGames,
    };
  }),

In my main charting component I fetch this data using
const { data: gamesData, isLoading: loadingGamesData } = api.game.getGames.useQuery();
I am presenting the data in a heatmap and the heatmap takes around 10 seconds to load. The dataset will only be updated once a day when that day's games are finished. How can I cache this data for 1 day to reduce the load time and database requests every time the page is opened and refreshed?
I have tried changing the staleTime and gcTime for React Query but that has not helped. I have also tried what the trpc docs suggest at https://trpc.io/docs/server/caching.
export function TRPCReactProvider(props: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const queryClient = getQueryClient();
  queryClient.setDefaultOptions({
    queries: {
      staleTime: 12 * (60 * 60 * 1000), // 12 hours
      gcTime: 12 * (60 * 60 * 1000), // 12 hours
    },
  });

  const [trpcClient] = useState(() =>
    api.createClient({
      links: [
        loggerLink({
          enabled: (op) =>
            process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ||
            (op.direction === "down" && op.result instanceof Error),
        }),
        unstable_httpBatchStreamLink({
          transformer: SuperJSON,
          url: getBaseUrl() + "/api/trpc",
          headers: () => {
            const headers = new Headers();
            headers.set("x-trpc-source", "nextjs-react");
            const ONE_DAY_IN_SECONDS = 60 * 60 * 24;
            headers.set(
              "cache-control",
              `s-maxage=${ONE_DAY_IN_SECONDS}, stale-while-revalidate=${ONE_DAY_IN_SECONDS}`,
            );
            return headers;
          },
        }),
      ],
    }),
  );

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <api.Provider client={trpcClient} queryClient={queryClient}>
        {props.children}
      </api.Provider>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}


The primary problem with your approach is that you are not utilizing features of Next.js correctly, because:
A) By fetching from a Client Component you are adding the need for a middle man (your API), which adds latency. Furthermore, the client will have to receive all of the 70k records and, I assume, calculate the values for the heatmap, which is not ideal to say the least.
B) Caching on the client might help if users navigate through the app and back to your heatmap, but given that you only have one page, I don't see a lot of use in that.

The most promising approach would be to use Next.js's ISR-Feature (Incremental Static Regeneration) in order to fetch the data, do your calculations for the heatmap on the server, and then cache this data for the desired duration by using the export const revalidate variable. Given that you use tRPC, you would need to instantiate a tRPC Client that can run on the Server and use it to fetch the data in a Server Component, while leveraging ISR.
An example of the top of my head could look like this (Haven't tested it):
serverClient.ts
export const trpcProxyClient = createTRPCProxyClient<AppRouter>({
    transformer: superjson,
    links: [
        httpBatchLink({
            url: getBaseUrl() + "/api/trpc",
        }),
    ],
});

export const tRPCServerClient = createServerSideHelpers({
    client: trpcProxyClient,
});

page.tsx
(assuming you are using the App Router)
// 1 day in minutes
export const revalidate = 1440

// calculate expensive stuff here
const expensiveCalculationForHeatmap = (games) => {}
 
export default async function Page() {
 const { data } = await tRPCServerClient.games.getAll.fetch()
 const transformedData = expensiveCalculationForHeatmap(data)
  return (
   <HeatmapClientComponent data={transformedData}/>
  )
}

